# App crashes when pushing view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I have a view controller which plays a video in `viewDidLoad`. I have an observer that checks to see when the video is finished and when it detects that the video is finished a method is called which pushes a view controller on to the stack. When this method is called, however, a get the following error in the console:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSPathStore2 setView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc6ef8e0'`

The code i use is shown below:

```
....
....
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(advanceToNextView) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];  
....
....
- (void) advanceToNextView {

    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"spoonVC"];


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. I have checked and double-checked the storyboard identifier is correct.

Comment: It looks like some memory used by your app may be getting clobbered somewhere.  -[NSPathStore2 setView:] means "setView" is getting called on an NSPathSTore2 instance, which shouldn't be happening. Have you run the profile and eliminated memory leaks yet?

Comment: @BrianV No I haven't. I've never run the profile before and don't know much about it. I'm using ARC and, rightly or wrongly, assumed memory leaks weren't a problem?

Comment: @garethdn That would be the idea, though I've noticed a surprising number of SO posts related to ARC with users having similar problems.

Comment: I ran the profile just there checking for memory leaks but saw no spikes anywhere at all. There was stuff going on in memory allocations alright but i honestly don't understand any of it.

Comment: Have you checked that self.navigationController.view is not nil?

Comment: @bbodayle If i do `NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.view);` immediately before i push i get the following: `<UILayoutContainerView: 0x98275b0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9827650>>`. I guess that means it's not nil?

Comment: What about trying [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:controller cache:NO];

Comment: @bbodayle I get incompatible pointer types, `UIViewController to UIView`.

Comment: If i use `controller.view` it pushes to the next view controller but without any kind of animation, it just flashes to the next screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It found a solution. The way to produce transition animations doesn't seem to be consistent but the following seems to work well for me.

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page2"];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip transition" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:
     UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                           forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your this code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

BY:

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```